# Сan not compose the correct SQL query for my case

Tags: mysql

I need to select contacts

1. where field "email" = value "email1" OR field "name" = value "name1"
2. where field "email" = value "email1" AND field "name" = value "name1"

I have solution SQL query for first condition OR

```
SELECT v.contact_id 
FROM values v
INNER JOIN fields f ON f.id = v.field_id
INNER JOIN contacts c ON c.id = v.contact_id
WHERE (f.tag = 'email' AND v.value = 'email1' AND f.listing_id = 1) 
   OR (f.tag = 'name' AND v.value = 'name1' AND f.listing_id = 1)
```

But if I change OR in the beginning of fifth line to AND it of course won't work

```
SELECT v.contact_id 
FROM values v
INNER JOIN fields f ON f.id = v.field_id
INNER JOIN contacts c ON c.id = v.contact_id
WHERE (f.tag = 'email' AND v.value = 'email1' AND f.listing_id = 1) 
  AND (f.tag = 'name' AND v.value = 'name1' AND f.listing_id = 1)
```

Please help me to improve this query to work in both options, i will be very grateful for help with solving this problem (mysql db)

Database scheme: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIaba.png

Database values:

Table groups

```
id | name
---+--------
1  | group1
```

Table contacts

```
id | group_id
---+----------
1  | 1
2  | 1
```

Table fields

```
id | group_id | tag
---+----------+--------
1  | 1        | email
2  | 1        | name
3  | 1        | email
4  | 1        | name
```

Table values

```
id | contact_id | field_id | value
---+------------+----------+----------
1  | 1          | 1        | email1
2  | 1          | 2        | name1
2  | 2          | 3        | email2
4  | 2          | 4        | name2
```

Comment: MySql <> Postgresql, please add the correct tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fot the second query (AND), try this query :

```
SELECT a.contact_id
  FROM 
     ( SELECT v.contact_id
         FROM values v
        INNER JOIN fields f
           ON f.id = v.field_id
        INNER JOIN contacts c
           ON c.id = v.contact_id
        WHERE (f.tag = 'email' AND v.value = 'email1' AND f.listing_id = 1)
     ) AS a
 INNER JOIN 
     ( SELECT v.contact_id
         FROM values v
        INNER JOIN fields f
           ON f.id = v.field_id
        INNER JOIN contacts c
           ON c.id = v.contact_id
        WHERE (f.tag = 'name' AND v.value = 'name1' AND f.listing_id = 1)
     ) AS b
    ON a.contact_id = b.contact_id
```

or this simpler query :

```
SELECT v.contact_id
  FROM values v
 INNER JOIN fields f
    ON f.id = v.field_id
 INNER JOIN contacts c
    ON c.id = v.contact_id
 WHERE (f.tag = 'email' AND v.value = 'email1' AND f.listing_id = 1)
    OR (f.tag = 'name' AND v.value = 'name1' AND f.listing_id = 1)
 GROUP BY v.contact_id
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: That is the problem. In one case i need to get get queries by email OR name equality in another case where email AND name are equal and this query not working for second case. Please help if can

Comment: OK got it, answer updated.

Comment: It seems to work. Thank you very much!